# Windows IOT app add parameter

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot

I am using IOT on a rpi3 to fire up a browser what I need to do is add a parameter so that I can run the same image with slightly modified behaviour instead of having to produce multiple images. I was wondering if it is possible to fire the app and pass a simple parameter
Something like -

C:\Data\Users\administrator\Documents>IoTStartup add headed App[*parameter*]

and then pick up the parameter in the c# application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is impossible to fire the app via passing a simple parameter like your mentions,please see [Windows 10 IoT Core Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils).
But I think there is another way to satisfy your needs, you can use a configuration file saved with your parameter data, when you want to change the 
 behavior, you just need to modify the config file.So that you can use a same image.Please refer to this article([Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)).

Comment: Good call, came up with a similar methodology using text file(the app doesn't have a config as such) but originally was looking at ip addresses and have even considered machine name as I am looking for the same functionality with the addition of a location (as you see from above passing that into the IoTStartup would be a way of differentiation)